# Linq data not updating form after postback

Tags: asp.net, linq

In my application, I have a form that users fill out, then gets approved by a manager.  I have various types of forms that all use the same process, so the approval buttons are all done via a user control (which includes the functionality to update the data in the database and call the postback).

However, once I click on the "Approve" button (which is in the user control), the form information doesn't update (it still says "unapproved").  A postback is definitely happening, but not sure why the page isn't updating properly.

I can confirm that the change are being made - when I manually reload the page, it gets updated - but not on the post back.

What am I missing here?

My page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ID;
    // ensure that there's an ID set in the query string
    if (Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"], out ID))
        PopulatePage(ID);
    else
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");          
    }
}

protected void PopulatePage(int ID)
{
    using (WOLinqClassesDataContext db = new WOLinqClassesDataContext())
    {
        lblStatus.Text = wo.Workorder.status;
        ....
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the Page_Load happens before the code in the submit button. To check this just use a couple of breakpoints. So the page loads the old data since the new data are not saved yet.

You should call a method to load the data inside the OnClick method of the Approve button.

Comment: This is exactly it. The Page_Load runs, then the changes get made to the record. Perfect... thanks Davide!

Comment: Any idea how to call the PopulatePage() method from my user control then?

Comment: Used this to call the page method from a user control: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-Parent-Page-method-from-Child-Usercontrol-using-Reflection-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Maybe you should also move the PopulatePage() in the Page_Load event into an if(!Page.IsPostBack) {...} in order to load the data only once on postbacks

Answer (score 1):

After you've submitted the changes to the database, try running `db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues)` to force the changes to be reloaded into the data context.